# How can I return compact head() and tail() results from the same code line with Rmarkdown/Knitr?

Tags: r, concatenation, knitr, head, r-markdown

**Goal:**  I want to return adjacent or at least compact results for `head()` and `tail()` using one line of code in Rmarkdown/Knitr.

I realize I can use `c()` for certain functions on the same code line and print on the same result line, e.g., `c(mean(vector), sd(vector))` will return `## [1] 20.663  6.606`.

However, if I try `c(head(data), tail(data))` I get a list, instead of a matrix/df and if I use `head(data); tail(data)` the results will display contiguously(?) top/bottom in the R console but return only `tail(data)` results in Rmarkdown/Knitr.

**Repro steps:**

1. Create an Rmd file with the following R chunk:

   ````
   ```{r Load Data, cache=TRUE,echo=TRUE}

   require("datasets") ## ensure User has the R datasets package installed
   data("ToothGrowth") ## load the ToothGrowth dataset
   head(ToothGrowth, n = 2); tail(ToothGrowth, n = 2) ## attempt compact results

   ```
   ````
2. Ctrl+shift+k to knit the Rmd or otherwise select the Knit HTML action.

**Relevant result:**

```
    ##    len    supp dose
    ## 59 29.4   OJ    2
    ## 60 23.0   OJ    2
```

**FYI settings:**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4     evaluate_0.5.3   formatR_0.10     htmltools_0.2.4  knitr_1.6       
[6] rmarkdown_0.2.46 stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.0.2      yaml_2.1.11
```

Comment: Try `cbind(head(data), tail(data))`.

Comment: `update.packages()` as **knitr** FAQ 1 says: http://bit.ly/knitr-faq

Comment: @Yihui.  That did appear to fix the unexpected behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knitr seems to have a bug, (inherited from the evaluate package) and does not produce two printed results from expressions on the same line separated by semicolons.

The closes you might get to what you want could be using

```
> rbind(head(ToothGrowth, 2), tail(ToothGrowth, 2))
    len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2  11.5   VC  0.5
59 29.4   OJ  2.0
60 23.0   OJ  2.0
```

Comment: or `do.call(rbind, lapply(c("head", "tail"), do.call, list(n=2, x=iris)))`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the bug you reported a long time ago, and the fixed version has been on CRAN for four months (http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/evaluate/NEWS). In this case, **knitr** FAQ 1 applies again: http://bit.ly/knitr-faq

Comment: @Bill Venables.  Thanks for the reply.  After doing the update suggested by Yihui, it looks like the best solution is, as I figured (unless someone posts something better) using `rbind()` because the `;` option actually gives the full output (observations + column headers) _beneath_ the first two observations.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the function `headTail` from the `psych` package. We pass ther argument `ellipsis = FALSE` so head and tail are not separated by dots.

```
library(psych)    
headTail(ToothGrowth, top = 2, bottom = 2, ellipsis = FALSE)
```

**Output**:

```
    len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2  11.5   VC  0.5
59 29.4   OJ  2.0
60 23.0   OJ  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this one

```
cbind(head(ToothGrowth, n = 2), tail(ToothGrowth, n = 2))

   len supp dose  len supp dose
1  4.2   VC  0.5 29.4   OJ    2
2 11.5   VC  0.5 23.0   OJ    2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  My concern with this solution is I'm unclear the final three columns are from observations 59/60, instead of 1/2.  To preserve the observation/row integrity, I would prefer `rbind()`.  However, `rbind()` consumes 2 more lines of output.  (The only reason I'm concerned about using 2 more lines is I have a limited amount of space allotted.)

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a column with row names?

```
library("datasets")
data("ToothGrowth")

# Add a leading column with row names
add_n_line <- function(df) {
  col_names <- colnames(df)
  df$n <- rownames(df)
  df[, c("n", col_names)]
}

print(cbind(add_n_line(head(ToothGrowth, n = 2)),
            add_n_line(tail(ToothGrowth, n = 2))),
      row.names = FALSE)

 ## n  len supp dose  n  len supp dose
 ## 1  4.2   VC  0.5 59 29.4   OJ    2
 ## 2 11.5   VC  0.5 60 23.0   OJ    2
```